# How does one compare items in a list sequentially?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm VERY new to coding and am playing through some toy problems to learn but have hit a wall with this one. (yes, I know I don't make good variable names).

I am trying to find the sum of all digits that match the next digit in the list. I got it to look at the items in sequence but it seems to get tripped up when it hits a duplicate. I ran the following code to check my progress:

```
code_string = "9511484596541141557316984781494999"
list(code_string)
for n in code_string:
   nextn = code_string[code_string.index(n)+1]
   if n == nextn:
      print(n)
```

and all I get is:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Why is it jumping around in my list rather than moving onto the next in sequence? Does it have something to do with converting a string to a list?
I want to do eventually do this with a MUCH larger list.

Comment: what is the expected output? perhaps can provide with small string example.

Comment: Try printing `code_string.index(n)` as well.

Comment: `list(code_string)` isn't doing anything useful. and you can iterate on a string all right

Comment: `index` returns the _first_ index of the digit in the string. Pretty useless here. You need `enumerate` but test for length else +1 is out of bounds

Comment: Hint: keep track of the indices as you're iterating with `enumerate`.

Answer (score 6):

`index` returns the *first* index of the digit in the string and performs a `O(n)` lookup on the string. You don't want to use that.

Either use `enumerate` to yield the index & the value (but you have to test if the index is not the last one else this +1 will make your program crash) or interleave (`zip`) the string with a sliced version lacking the first element: this provides an item and its successor.

Then you can compare:

```
code_string = "9511484596541141557316984781494999"
for d1,d2 in zip(code_string,code_string[1:]):
   if d1==d2:
      print(d1)
```

outputs:

```
1
1
5
9
9
```

finding the sum of those numbers can be achieved in a classic way, or in one line using `sum` and a generator comprehension (convert the digit to integer prior to summing):

```
result = sum(int(d1) for d1,d2 in zip(code_string,code_string[1:]) if d1==d2)
```

(which is `25`)

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping track of both indexes instead of iterating through the actual items in the list:

```
for i in range(0,len(code_string)):
    if code_string[i] == code_string[i+1]:
        print(code_string[i])
```